# HTML/PHP Group table by month with colors

Tags: php, html, sql

I created a code that allows me to print HTML table rows from a database table and then sort them by date.

The problem that the date is stored as VARCHAR (I'm not the one who started this project and the database is already active and in use through a php web app), which is why I used the "str_to_date" to turn it into an actual date datatype and be able to sort them, the format used here is dd/mm/yyyy.

What I need help with is in grouping them by month, keep the sorting but the rows with the same month to have same color or have a separation from the others.

I checked existing forums for an answer to no avail.

```
<?php
$est_query = "SELECT * FROM t1_estimaciones WHERE EstComentario = 'PENDIENTE PAGO' ORDER BY str_to_date(EstFechaPago,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC;";

$est_result = mysqli_query($link, $est_query);
while($est_row = mysqli_fetch_array($est_result)){
    $est_idtabla1 = $est_row['idTabla1'];
    $est_subtotal = $est_row['EstSubtotal'];
    $est_iva = $est_row['EstIVA'];
    $est_importe = $est_row['EstImporte'];
    $est_fecha_ingreso = $est_row['EstFechaIngreso'];
    $est_fecha_pago = $est_row['EstFechaPago'];
    $est_num_factura = $est_row['EstNumFactura'];
    $est_comentario = $est_row['EstComentario'];

    $est_po_query = "SELECT * FROM Tabla_1 WHERE Num = '$est_idtabla1'";
    $est_po_result = mysqli_query($link,$est_po_query);
    $est_po_row = mysqli_fetch_array($est_po_result);
    $est_po = $est_po_row['PO'];

    echo '<tr style="border-bottom:thin solid #949494;height:60px;">';
    echo '<td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:whitesmoke;">' . $est_po . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:10%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">$' . number_format($est_subtotal) . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:10%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">$' . number_format($est_iva) . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:10%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">$' . number_format($est_importe) . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:15%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">' . $est_fecha_ingreso . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:15%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">' . $est_fecha_pago . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:10%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">' . $est_num_factura . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width:20%;text-align:center;border-left:thin solid #949494;color:whitesmoke;">' . $est_comentario . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you update the existing database table to add a column for the date but in the proper date type? So that you can grab the varchar date and set that proper date column, then handle any grouping or sorting in the query

Comment: Thank Dharman, I'll do it.

Comment: @Anthony Ok, I'm going to add the date column, however, since there's already a lot of rows in the VARCHAR column and all of it is in the format "dd/mm/yyyy", is there a way to transfer each date value into the new column?

Comment: Something like `UPDATE my_table
SET
my_proper_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(string_date_column,'%d/%m/%Y')
` based on using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) mysql function

Comment: But I'd definitely give that a test drive in some non production tables first.

Comment: You should be able to resolve the issue by converting, then sorting the date using epoch seconds, and creating a loop that assigns the desired color to each month.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach for this type of problem. Here's a very simplified example that should show the concept.

Initialize a variable that will hold the value of the column you want to use to define your groups.

```
$group_column = null;
```

Then, as you fetch rows, compare the value of that column in each row to the variable. If it's different, start a new group.

```
while ($row == $query->fetch()) {
    if ($row['group_column'] !== $group_column) {
        // this row is different than the last one
        // so start a new group
    }
    // output the row

    // the "current" value becomes the "previous" value for the next iteration
    $group_column = $row['group_column'];
}
```

The variable takes the value of the current row on each iteration, so on the next iteration you're comparing the current value to the previous value. In your case you'll need to use a substring of the date, or select the month in your query.

Obviously you have to sort your data in an order that uses the column you want to group by in order for this to work.